# How do I add SE error bars to my barplot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, errorbar

I made a simple barplot with ggplot2 comparing the mean lifespan (age) of males and females for 2 insect species. 
My code looks like this, with "dataset" being, well, my data set...

```
    gplot(dataset, aes(Species, Age, fill=Sex))+
stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge")+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("Grey25", "Grey"))+
theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,15))
```

I tried using the following code to manually enter the value of the mean±SE to set the limits for the error bar. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume mean=10 and SE=0.5 for males of species1.

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=9.5, ymax=10.5),width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
```

This code does indeed work, but it sets the same error bars for each bar in my plot.

How can I add error bars equal to the corresponding SE for each bar in my plot?

I am fairly new to ggplot and R in general so any help/advice is welcome.

Comment: You need to first calculate the errors and means for each bar and mutate them into your dataset. then set the `ymin` and `ymax` to those columns.

Comment: This may help you. http://environmentalcomputing.net/plotting-with-ggplot-bar-plots-with-error-bars/

Comment: I can't seem to get the `ymin`and `ymax`to work properly.
I followed the link you provided and tried the example with the iris data and that does not work either...I can't get passed `group_by(Species)`. 
The following error message shows up : Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "factor".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You don't need more than to add `stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge")` to your plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, price, fill = color)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean, position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge")
```

[image]

If you prefer to calculate the values beforehand, you could do it like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
pdata <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  summarise(new = list(mean_se(price))) %>% 
  unnest(new)


pdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cut, y = y, fill = color)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), position = "dodge")
```

Comment: The line of code you suggested I add worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can add an error bar on your barplot with the `geom_errorbar` geom.

You need to supply the `ymin` and `ymax`, so you need to compute it manually.

From the `geom_errorbar` help page:

```
p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.2)
```