# Error_bar and exercise

Tags: r, errorbar

Sorry my bad english, for not pasting the code, and for asking questions because I am not very familiar with R. I am a beginner. There's my notice and the graph I must find:

[image]

[image]

I read the R documentation to solve this problem but I was unable to figure out the solution.

[image]

Actually I found this with this script I used. But i've got not clue for adding errorbar I tried `geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se))` but surely I've mistaken myself

```
`rm(list=ls() )
library(dplyr) 
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
Sparrows <- read.delim("C:/Users/detar/Downloads/Sparrows.txt")
View(Sparrows)
str(Sparrows)
jitter<-filter(Sparrows,day == 4)
x<-ggplot(jitter,
          aes (x = rank_name,
               y = logit.motility,)) + geom_point(colour = "cyan") +
  xlab("Social Rank") + 
  ylab("Logit(Proportion of motile sperm") +
  labs(title =("Ejaculate quality covaries with social rank
 of male House Sparrows")) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("D","S1","S2","S3"), labels=c("Dominant", "Subordinate 1", "Subordinate 2", "Subordinate 3"))
x2<-x + theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14))
```

Thanks for your help
Benjamin

So I added

```
table <- jitter %>% 
group_by(rank_name) %>% 
summarize(Mean = mean(logit.motility, na.rm=TRUE),
                SEM = sd( logit.motility, na.rm=TRUE) / sqrt(15)
  ) %>% as.data.frame()

x2<-x + theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14)) + geom_errorbar(data = summary_table, 
                                          aes(x =rank_name,
                                          y =logit.motility,
                                          ymin =Mean - SEM ,
                                          ymax =Mean + SEM ,
                                          colour = "black",
                                          width = 1 ))
```

But an error occured
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: y So am i mistaken in  those arguments

And a new time, i thank you

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875113/8245406). Near duplicate, the only difference is that this question's graph is a point graph.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! a new time i come to you

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is identical to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44875113/8245406) but all possible duplicates I have found are about bar plots, so here is one answer to a question about scatter plots.

First, the data, since the question has none.

```
df1 <- iris[4:5]
```

Now the graph. Any of `geom_errorbar` or `stat:summary` with `geom = "errorbar"` could be used.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = "lightblue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "lightblue") +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = mean) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, 
               position = "dodge", width = 0.2)
```

[image]