How to create custom stats function in ggplot?
If I have data iris. I want to make a graph that shows mean by bars and se by error bars. I know I can use aggregate to make a separate dataset outside of ggplot. But, I want to know how I can do this by skipping a step, if I can by using stat functions inside ggplot.
Getting the means from the raw data was easy.
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='summary', fun=mean) 

Getting the standard error is harder.
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='summary', fun=mean) + 
  geom_errorbar(stat='summary', fun=function(y){sd(y)/sqrt(length(y))})

{Plot with no error bars}

ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='summary', fun=mean) + 
  stat_summary(fun=function(y){sd(y)/sqrt(length(y))}, geom='errorbar')

{Plot with no error bars}

Normally, with an aggregated dataset, I would input ymax=mean+se and so forth inside geom_errorbar, however, I can't figure out how to do this while computing these means and standard errors inside ggplot. Any advice?

Seems like dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44872951/how-do-i-add-se-error-bars-to-my-barplot-in-ggplot2 ? Or is the idea you want to do a different function and se is just an example?

+ stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se)?

Thanks! Did not know about mean_se

To do it yourself, supply fun.ymin and fun.ymax, or use fun.data and return an appropriate data.frame. See the examples in ?stat_summary.
